# Как найти Альт символ?

Tags: php, html, css

Из вк надо спарсить контент где встречается зеленая галочка, по сути альт код вроде бы нашел ✅ но он не находится, такое ощущение как будто это разные альты, как можно определить альт скопированного символа, мб сервис есть какой?

mystring = ✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅

```
$mystring = $test_split[3];
$findme   = '&#9989;';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Заметьте, что используется ===.  Использование == не даст верного 
// результата, так как 'a' в нулевой позиции.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring1'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring1'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: Попробуйте искать ✅ -, а не `&#9989;`.

Comment: @And Пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Начнем с того что строчка `$mystring = '$test_split[3]';` - не будет работать т.к. вы планируете, во-вторых, что вам мешает глянуть содержимое текста, который вы получаете и посмотреть как там выглядит ваш альт?

Comment: У меня есть входная информация: Строка ✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅

1. Мне необходимо узнать какой используемый Альт в строке.(На данный момент этот Альт &#9989; я нашел в гугле он был более похож на те что в строке и не факт что это он) Мб есть какой то сервис/метод который бы мог перевести Символ из буфера в альт код
2. мне необходимо найти есть ли совпадение Альта в строке.
3. '$test_split[3]'; исправил, это я экспериментировал, случайно добавил

Comment: Нашел еще такой же символ &#x2705; Выглядит абсолютно так же. Похоже под символом скрывается другой альт и не понятно как его узнать

Answer (score 0):

У ВК свои смайлы, то что я искал

## 590

✅
&#_9989;
2705

Если кому то будет полезно весь список: https://vk.com/pages?oid=-42154384&p=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_17